# Remove key=value from url

Tags: java, url

I need a java library that will make it easy to edit URLs. URLs are given as Strings and must be returned as strings.

I need things such as removing `key=value` pairs and leaving the url clean and with ?s and &s properly placed.

Comment: I would recommend you familiarize yourself with Java [regular expressions and pattern matching](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html) capabilities for strings. There is probably no need for a special library here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [regular expressions and pattern matching](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/pattern.html):

For instance:

```
String original = "http://www.someHost.com/somePage?key1=value1&key2=value2";
Pattern keyValPattern = Pattern.compile("\\p{Alpha}\\w+=[^&]+");
Matcher m = keyValPattern.matcher(original);  
m.find(); // find an occurence of key=value pair
String keyVal = m.group(); // get the value of the found pair
// keyVal will be 'key1=value1'
int start = m.start(); // the start index of 'key1=value1' in the original string
int end = m.end(); //the end index of 'key1=value1' in the original string
m.find();
String keyVal2 = m.group();// keyVal2 will be 'key2=value2'
// ... etc
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the Java `URL` class to parse the original string and change the parameters, then just `toString()` it again for your result.

Answer (score 0):

This is simple [utility class](http://ostermiller.org/utils/src/CGIParser.java.html) which can help. I wouldn't use whole library just for that, better is to see what you needs and create your own utility class with methods which you need.